# artisan migrate results: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 on LUMEN / LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to run `php artisan migrate` command but I am getting the following error.
I have looked at many forums and tried several solutions but nothing solved my problem.
What is going on?

[image]

-

Migrations:

- http://pastebin.com/mDFa1suK
- http://pastebin.com/tFWj9bEd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not create "produtos" table with a foreign key reference before creating "categorias" table

i suggest to change to change date in migration files name to re-order migration

so that migration of "categorias" table will run first

i hope that answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that in your migration files, there are no table name `cremasco.#sql-3076_1e` but the error showing cannot create that table.

pls check your **migration table** in you database see if it has the `cremasco.#sql-3076_1e`. and run this in your command line :

> `composer dumpautoload` then try again to migrate the database `php artisan migrate`

if the problem still exist then you need to drop your databases, and migrate again.

> This problem exist because we deleted the files migration but the
>   table migration in database still has it

.